# Creating an array and pasting to set cols in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to try to create an array in VBA and paste it to back into another sheet in the same workbook. I need an array of 50 random integer values, these 50 values need to come from 4 different sources, Source A = 15 values, Source B = 15 Values, Source C = 10 values, Source D = 10 Values. If the array cannot be filled to 15 or 10 by the source, I would like to fill what is left with source A. Here is some of the sample data i have

```
Sample Data 'This is redundant and can be replicated to create up to 50 entries, but the logic will stem from these entries.
    Name Number      Source
    Bill  123456789  Type A
    Bill  213456789  Type B
    Bill  313456789  Type C
    Bill  413456789  Type D
    ...
    ...       
    ...
    Mary  231234567  Type A
    Mary  231234567  Type B
    Mary  231234567  Type C
    ...
    ...       
    ...
    Tom   234567891  Type A
    ...
    ...       
    ...

Sub RandomNumberGen()
 'Create Arrays for each type of inspections
   Dim TypeAArray() As Variant
   Dim TypeBArray() As Variant
   Dim TypeCArray() As Variant
   Dim TypeDArray() As Variant

 'Set Arrays range
   Dim my_OverRange As Range
   LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Set my_TypeARange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
   ReDim ColumnOverArray(LastRow) 'Re size your array to fit data
   ColumnOverArray = my_TypeARange 'add data to array

 'Create loop to cycle through arrays and gather Random values?
 'This is where im at so far. Im able to create an array and 
 'paste back into excel. Either i need to run a loop to cycle 
 'through or create 3 more arrays and get random values from the 
 'ranges.
   MyTypeARange().Value = MyTypeARange.Random(15)
   MyTypeBRange().Value = Random(15)
   MyTypeCRange().Value = Random(10)
   MyTypeDRange().Value = Random(10)

 'Paste Random Values into sheet
```

My end result should look something like this.

```
    Number   Source
    123456789  Type A
    ...
    ...
    ...
    123456789  Type B
    ...
    ...
    ...
    123456789  Type C
    ...
    ...
    ...
    123456789  Type D
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Firstly, please show us what you tried by your own. Secondly, what you want is not so clear... Where from to be taken those "50 random integer values"? What do you mean by "Source A, B, C and D"? What should they be? Ranges? Ranges bigger then 15 where from to randomly extract 10 to 15 values? Should those ranges be columns, rows, or ranges containing more than one row/column? Then, what kind to be the final array? A 1D type? If you better explain what you really try accomplishing, we will maybe better understand how to help you. In the way it looks, it will be a serios candidate do be deleted

Comment: I updated my entry, i hope that this helps clear up any confusion. I'm a bit confused myself as to what you're asking about ranges, but i think the above code will help. The random values need to contain a range of numbers consisting of 4 source points, A,B,C and D. These ranges need to contain 15 values for source A, 15 values for source B, 10 Values for source C and 10 values for source D.

Comment: You updated it, but no more light has been produced, I am afraid. You only prove that you do not understand too much from VBA. You did not declare `ColumnOverArray` but use `ReDim` for it. You did it for a 1D array, but from a range, even if containing a single column, it will be a 2D array. Where do you use it? `MyTypeARange().Value` does not have any meaning in VBA. An array does not have such a property. `ColumnOverArray` is not used, anyhow. Since when do you work in VBA? Please, better explain **in words** what you want accomplishing. And try answer my questions, please, if you need help.

Comment: If you know asking it may be a very good place to receive help. If, let us say, will use three column ranges from excel, each of them much larger than 15, something like "C2:C50", "E2:E75", "G2:G50" and "J2:J50" and I will show you how to extract random elements/rows from each of them (15 from the first two and 10 from the next) and place the extracted elements in a common array, then dropping this array content in a range, let us say, "A2:A50", will it be considered a good catch of what you try accomplishing?

Comment: Or create four arrays as you have in your code, will it be OK? You must only be able to explain what you need. We here are not mind readers... At least, answer the questions in the way they have been asked.

Comment: Yes, there is always multiple ways to a solution. Whichever one is the best/simplest method. I originally thought creating 4 unique arrays to hold the "types" then selecting random numbers from them.

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next code. It will randomly extract elements from the ranges (to be larger than 15) in columns "C", "E", "G" and "J" and placed them in the four arrays you used in your code, but differently dimensioned. These four arrays are placed in a jagged array (an array of arrays) and randomly loaded. The code stops after each array has been processed and visually show in `Immediate Window` (being in VBE, `Ctrl + G`). Please, press `F5` after each such stop. The content of each array will be dropped in A:A, one on top of the other:

```
Sub ExtractUniqueRndNumbersFromRanges()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arrInit, rndNo As Long
   Dim TypeAArray(1 To 15, 1 To 1) As Variant, TypeBArray(1 To 15, 1 To 1)
   Dim TypeCArray(1 To 10, 1 To 1) As Variant, TypeDArray(1 To 10, 1 To 1) As Variant
   Dim jagArr, colsArr, filt As String, ii As Long, i As Long, lastERA As Long
   
   jagArr = Array(TypeAArray, TypeBArray, TypeCArray, TypeDArray) 'create a jagged array (an array of arrays)
   colsArr = Array("C", "E", "G", "J")                                             'create an array of columns used to extract random elements
   
   Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2") 'it may be any sheet
   sh.Range("A:A").ClearContents 'in order to repeat the code if some modifications needed
   For ii = 0 To UBound(jagArr)  'iterate between the arrays of the jagged array
        lastRow = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, colsArr(ii)).End(xlUp).Row  'last row
        arrInit = Application.Transpose(sh.Range(colsArr(ii) & "2:" & colsArr(ii) & lastRow).value) 'create a 2D array from the range
        For i = 1 To UBound(jagArr(ii))
                Randomize
                rndNo = Int((UBound(arrInit) - LBound(arrInit) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(arrInit))
                jagArr(ii)(i, 1) = arrInit(rndNo) 'fill the A array with the random array elemengt
                filt = arrInit(rndNo) & "$$$": arrInit(rndNo) = filt 'make the array element unique, to be removed
                arrInit = filter(arrInit, filt, False) 'eliminate the already extracted number
        Next i
        
        Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(jagArr(ii)), "|"): Stop  'visually check the filled array content in Immediate Window
        lastERA = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last empty row in A:A
        sh.Range("A" & lastERA).Resize(UBound(jagArr(ii)), 1).value = jagArr(ii)
    Next ii
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

If something not clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: I tested this code, it works but its putting out random numbers of various types(15 various numbers (good) from various types(bad). I get a bit lost at the first loops which i think is were its gather the cols of types then the next for loop will randomize these and fill in the number. I almost think having one array and then just copy a random number if it is of the correct type.  ie. Array"X" = if Source is type "X" then random number. I appreciate your response.

Comment: @Aaron I cannot get you... I told you that the above code **fills the four arrays with random numbers COLLECTED from that mentioned ranges**. They **already contain the randomly chosen numbers (from the mentioned ranges/arrays)**. What do you mean bay  "various types(bad)"? The numbers type **should be placed by you in the ranges where to be taken from**! Do you want randomly collected numbers or **building such numbers from a specific interval, let us say, 2500 to 5000**? The code does exactly what you suggest in your last paragraph. Iterating between the arrays in the jagged array does it!